# usage of but & although

Tags: word-usage

Do the following sentences sound natural?

> 1. **But** I didn’t know that then, **although** I learned it later.
> 2. I tried doing the accounts, **but although** I knew some maths I found it very difficult.

I kind of think sentence 1 is not natural because "but" is at the beginning of the sentence and there is also "although". What is your opinion?

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: Maybe because "but" is at the beginning in sentence one. Do you think both the two sentences are natural?

Comment: Not just *but*, *although* is also an extra word to me. *I didn't know that then, I learned it later.* But let the natives come and put light on it.

Comment: I'm completely baffled by the fact that apparently ***three*** users have closevoted this as "proofreading". The OP clearly sets out the cause for concern (there's something "unusual" about starting an utterance with ***but***). And this directly relates to a genuine difference between how the two *oppositional conjunctions* can be used, even though in some contexts they're synonymous and interchangeable. I think this is a good question that deserves to be *upvoted*, not closed.

Comment: You miss commas separating the clauses. *I tried doing the accounts, but, although I knew some maths, I found it very difficult.* The clause *although I knew some maths* is an interjection, and you need to separate it from the clause into which it's inserted (*but I found it very difficult*) using commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason OP's example #1 might seem "odd" is because *we don't have the full context*.

It's effectively meaningless to start a conversation or text with ***but***, because this particular ["contrastive conjunction"](http://www.rit.edu/ntid/rate/sea/processes/relationships/grammatical/logical/oppositionalcontrastive) almost *always* applies to something previously mentioned. Thus, sentence #1 is perfectly natural as a response in the following...

> *"You should have told me you had Aids when we first met!"*
>   *"But I didn't know that then, although I learned it later and have been meaning to tell you for a while"*

...where ***but*** contrasts with the preceding utterance by the other speaker, and ***although*** contrasts with the first part of the *second* speaker's utterance.

In OP's example #2, again, ***but*** contrasts with the preceding statement. But in this case, both the elements being contrasted by ***although*** come *after* the conjunction.

---

It's just about possible to start a "conversation/text" with ***but*** (you open the door to someone you weren't expecting to see, and exclaim *"But what are you doing here?"*), but that's an unusual/poetic/dated usage. In general, ***but*** always applies to something previously specified, whereas ***although*** can optionally be moved *before* its referent...

> *"My dog likes chocolate although it could kill him if he eats too much"* <sup>1</sup>
>    ...is equivalent to...
>    *"Although my dog likes chocolate it could kill him if he eats too much"*

Hopefully that shows how ***although*** can be placed in different positions. And if a previous speaker had said *"Any animal instinctively knows and seeks out the food its body needs to remain healthy"*, either of those last two examples could be preceded by ***but*** (introducing a refutation).

---

> <sup>1</sup> In this (but not the following) example, either conjunction works...
>   *"My dog likes chocolate **but** it could kill him if he eats too much"*

Answer (score -1):

Sentence 2 is fine.

As you suspect, sentence 1 isn't quite right, because the although is redundant. You can have either but or although in either place, but not both in the same sentence without it sounding odd.

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: It's my downvote, as explained by the answer I've just posted. Specifically, there's *nothing* wrong with OP's example #2, and ***although*** is not "redundant" (it contrasts *I found it difficult* **although** *I knew some maths*), whereas ***but*** contrasts *I tried doing the accounts* with the remainder of the sentence.